# How to Handle JSON Return Array?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've learnt quite a bit of XML handling, but I'm crap with JSON, and wondering how I would go about parsing the following data with PHP (or jquery).
If I were to

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://wthashtag.com/api/v2/trends/active.json");
```

(That's a Twitter JSON return of trends data)
then,

```
$obj = var_dump(json_decode($var));
```

The URL being the url variable in the json, Blah being the name variables, and text here, referring to the text: variable in the json
How would I take the input json of http://wthashtag.com/api/v2/trends/active.json, and output it as:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=blah">Blah</a><br>(text here)`

It's really confusing to me :S I've tried some other responses on SO and Google as well as the PHP manual, none yield successful results, the best I could get was echo'ing $obj as a json-decoded string with an object(stdclass) array everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a object that you receive after json_decode

```
<?php
$object = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://wthashtag.com/api/v2/trends/active.json"));

foreach($object->trends as $trend){
    echo '<a href="'.$trend->url.'">'.$trend->name.'</a><br />'.$trend->description->text.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: you still need to add error handling if request fails, decoding fails, array members are empty

Answer (score 1):

You can make `json_decode()` return an object or an array (by setting the second parameter to `true`). After that, you can use the values in that object/array (in `$obj` in your case) for further processing. Example:

```
foreach ( $obj->trends as $trend ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $trend['url'] . '">' . $trend['name'] . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `json_decode` you're creating an array. Do a `print_r` on the `json_decode($var)` and you'll get the multi-dimensional array structure - you'll then be able to do something like:

```
echo $jsonArray['something']['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<?php

$var = file_get_contents("http://wthashtag.com/api/v2/trends/active.json");
$json = json_decode($var);
foreach($json->trends as $lol){
      echo "<a href=".$lol->url.">".$lol->name."</a><br>";
}

?>
```